# Merge Values into Unique Columns

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have my Excel sheet below. I need to merge them to unique values.
[image: Excel Sheet Vaues]

Required Output:
[image: Output I Want]

Comment: Would you mind sharing what have you tried so far that didn't work?

Answer (score 0):

#### Step 1 - Create a list of unique names

Use the following formula where you want the first name to appear and copy down:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$A$7, MATCH(0, COUNTIF($F$1:F1,$A$2:$A$7), 0)),"")
```

Note there need to be a cell above this.  ie it cannot be in row 1. It is also an array formula so you will need to use <kbd>CONTROL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> instead of just <kbd>ENTER</kbd> when entering your formula.

#### Step 2 - Pull corresponding entries

Adjacent to the first entry use the following formula and copy down and to the right as needed:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(B:B,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($A$2:$A$8)/(($A$2:$A$8=$F2)*(B$2:B$8<>"")),1)),"")
```

The above formula is a regular formula but it does perform array like calculations withing the aggregate portion of the function.  Therefore avoid using full column references within the aggregate function.

[image: Sample]

Comment: HI All ,Thanks for the Quick response its working fine now.